# Understanding byref, ref and &

Tags: .net, f#, reference, parameter-passing, byref

Well, I came to understand that F# is able to manage references (some sort of C++ like references). This enables the possibilities to change value of parameters passed in functions and also enables the programmer to return more than a single value.
However here's what I need to know:

1. Ref keyword: The keyword `ref` is used to create, from a value, a reference to that value of the inferred type. So

   ```
   let myref = ref 10
   ```

   This means that F# will create an object of type `Ref<int>` putting there (in the mutable field) my `int 10`.

   OK. So I assume that `ref` is used to create instances of the `Ref<'a>` type. Is it correct?
2. Access value: In order to access a value stored in reference I can do this:

   ```
   let myref = ref 10
   let myval = myref.Value
   let myval2 = !myref
   ```

   While the `:=` operator just lets me edit the value like this:

   ```
   let myref = ref 10
   myref.Value <- 30
   myref := 40
   ```

   So `!` (Bang) dereferences my reference. And `:=` edit it. I suppose this is correct too.
3. The & operator: What does this operator do? Is it to be applied to a reference type? No, I guess it must be applied to a mutable value and this returns what? The reference? The address? If using interactive:

   ```
   let mutable mutvar = 10;;
   &a;;
   ```

   The last line throws an error so I do not understand what the `&` operator is for.
4. ByRef: What about `byref`? That's very important to me, but I realize I do not understand it.
   I understand it is used in function regarding parameter passing. One uses byref when he wants that the passed value can be edited (this is a bit against the functional languages' philosophy but f# is something more than that). Consider the following:

   ```
   let myfunc (x: int byref) =
       x <- x + 10
   ```

   This is strange. I know that if you have a reference `let myref = ref 10` and then do this to edit the value: `myref <- 10` it arises an error because it should be like this: `myref := 10`. However, the fact that in that function I can edit `x` using the `<-` operator means that `x` is not a reference, right?

   If I assume that `x` is not a reference, then I assume also that, in functions, when using `byref` on a parameter, that parameter can have the mutable syntax applied to. So it is just a matter of syntax, if I assume this I am OK, and, in fact, everything works (no compiler errors). However, what is `x`?
5. Calling functions: How can I use a function utilizing byref parameters?

   The `&` operator is involved but could you explain this better please? In this article: [MSDN Parameters and Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) the following example is provided:

   ```
   type Incrementor(z) =
       member this.Increment(i : int byref) =
          i <- i + z

   let incrementor = new Incrementor(1)
   let mutable x = 10
   // A: Not recommended: Does not actually increment the variable. (Me: why?)
   incrementor.Increment(ref x)
   // Prints 10.
   printfn "%d" x  

   let mutable y = 10
   incrementor.Increment(&y) (* Me: & what does it return? *)
   // Prints 11.
   printfn "%d" y 

   let refInt = ref 10
   incrementor.Increment(refInt) (* Why does it not work in A, but here it does? *)
   // Prints 11.
   printfn "%d" !refInt
   ```

Comment: Style tips: multiple question marks do not make your questions more "question-y" and they make you look a little silly: one is enough. Text in all caps is hard to read and is generally understood to mean that you're shouting: use [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (like italic and bold) for emphasis.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Ref keyword** Yes, when you write `let a = ref 10` you're essentially writing `let a = new Ref<int>(10)` where the `Ref<T>` type has a mutable field `Value`.

**Access value** The `:=` and `!` operators are just shortcuts for writing:

```
a.Value <- 10  // same as writing: a := 10
a.Value        // same as writing: !a
```

**ByRef** is a special type that can be (reasonably) used only in method parameters. It means that the argument should be essentially a pointer to some memory location (allocated on heap or stack). It corresponds to `out` and `ref` modifiers in C#. Note that you cannot create local variable of this type.

**The & operator** is a way to create a value (a pointer) that can be passed as an argument to a function/method expecting a `byref` type.

**Calling functions** the example with `byref` works because you're passing the method a reference to a local mutable variable. Via the reference, the method can change the value stored in that variable.

The following doesn't work:

```
let a = 10            // Note: You don't even need 'mutable' here
bar.Increment(ref a)
```

The reason is that you're creating a new instance of `Ref<int>` and you're copying the value of `a` into this instance. The `Increment` method then modifies the value stored on heap in the instance of `Ref<int>`, but you don't have a reference to this object anymore.

```
let a = ref 10
bar.Increment(a)
```

This works, because `a` is a value of type `Ref<int>` and you're passing a pointer to the heap-allocated instance to `Increment` and then get the value from heap-allocated reference cell using `!a`.

(You can use values created using `ref` as arguments for `byref` because the compiler handles this case specially - it will automatically take reference of the `Value` field because this is a useful scenario...).

Comment: Hoever I'm sorry Tomas, but when passing a ref to a function accepting a byref, the interpreter goes crazy...

Comment: @Andry: "crazy" in what sense? Behavior you didn't expect or some error message? (I'll be happy to clarify that part..)

Comment: Sorry for being late... Well it tells me that expects a ByRef<'a> but gets a Ref<'a>... that's what is gets me... The interpreter just does not accepts that argument :(

Comment: Just seen this as I was facing the same problem, If we have a byref<> in a win32 extern API then it requires a "&" operator to tell the compiler about the byref, otherwise as Tomas has said it should work with ref variables,

let mutable pid = 0u
GetWindowThreadProcessId(new IntPtr(phwnd),& pid) |> ignore