# Pass `out` parameter (as reference) in F#

Tags: .net, reference, f#, functional-programming

I want to call [`System.Uri.TryCreate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms131572.aspx):

```
let uriResult: System.Uri = ref (* what's here? *);
System.Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, uriResult)
```

As I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028580/603003), one has to pass a F# reference for .NET *out* parameters.

But how can I initialize my reference `uriResult` in my case?

I've tried creating a new, empty Uri object.

```
let uriResult: System.Uri = ref (new System.Uri());
```

> Error 1
> This expression was expected to have type
>        Uri
>   but here has type
>       'a ref

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in [Parameters and Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) on MSDN (see Passing by Reference), out parameters are automatically tuplized, so you can do this:

```
match System.Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute) with
| true, uriResult -> //OK
| _ -> //not a Uri
```