# Does it get copied? How passing reference and value types works under the hood

Tags: memory, f#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am wondering how passing `reference` and `value` types as arguments works under the hood and how that plays out in [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924/f-closure).

I was wondering how to deal with the risk of duplicating instances.
Also, [I may have to deal with large immutable data structures in the future.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

I have found only hints on the use of [mutable and reference cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028377/understanding-byref-ref-and). And again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221200/f-let-mutable-vs-ref). But this case I am interested in immutable value and reference types.

I tried to experiment but I did not figure out how to find out the address location of  stuff which is not `mutable`

```
let myfun x  = 
    printfn "pointer: %A" &x
```

results in the error:

> error FS0256: A value must be mutable in order to mutate the contents
>   or take the address of a value type, e.g. 'let mutable x = ...'

---

Is the variable copied when passed as a parameter?
I suppose that, dealing with immutable values, it would make no sense to "copy" argument values.

*Case 1: Value type*

```
let a = 10
let myfun x =
    printfn "x = %i" x
myfun a
```

*Case 2: Reference type*

```
type Test () = 
    member this.DoSomething () = printfn "Hello!"
let useTestType (x: Test) = x.DoSomething ()    
let testInstance = Test ()
useTestType testInstance
```

*Case 3: Class with a mutable*

```
type Test2 () =
    let mutable counter = 10
    member this.DoSomething () = printfn "Hello!"
let useTestType2 (x: Test2) = x.DoSomething ()
```

*Case 4: Closure* - 
No, it is not copied.

```
type Test3 () =
    let mutable counter = 10
    member this.DoSomething () = printfn "Hello!"
    member this.Counter = counter
    member this.AddCounter x = 
        counter <- counter + x

let ex = Test3 ()
let closure (x: Test3) = (fun variable ->
                            x.DoSomething ()
                            variable + x.Counter )

let funct = closure ex
let res = funct 20

ex.AddCounter 20
let res2 = funct 20
```

*Case 5: Other*

Are the edge cases I should keep in mind?

---

**For the big picture, this toy example simplifies one of issues I have in mind:**

In this toy example, we have a `DataDispatcher` class. The class contains an `Event` that can be triggered. The idea of the class is that it will take care of the gathering and aggregation of data. A `MaiboxProcessor` can subscribe and get data delivered.

```
let names = [ "Sensor1"; "Sensor2"; "Sensor3" ]
let bdays = [ "CCH15"; "BBH15"; "AAH15" ]
let dict = List.zip names bdays |> Map.ofList


type MsgToAgent = | Value of string []


let testAgent =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop () =
            async { 
                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                    match msg with
                    | Value array -> 
                        printfn "Array: %s" (String.concat ", " array)
                    return! loop ()}
        printfn "Hello World"
        loop ())



type DataDispatcher (dictionary) =     

    let available = new Event<Map<string,string>> ()  

    member this.ManualTrigger () = 
        available.Trigger dictionary
    member this.Subscribe (agent: MailboxProcessor<MsgToAgent>, names: string []) = 
        available.Publish.Add (fun dict ->
            let list = 
                names 
                |> Array.map dict.TryFind 
                |> Array.choose id
            agent.Post (Value list) )

let datadispatcher = DataDispatcher(dict)
datadispatcher.Subscribe (testAgent, [| "Sensor1"; "Sensor3" |]) 
datadispatcher.ManualTrigger ()
```

I suspected that this implementation would duplicate the `MailboxProcessor`, leading to a proliferation of agents active and looping in the memory. However, screen output suggests this is not the case.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks. The link does not answer the question.

Comment: Ah...closures. Nothing is magical about closures. They are just syntaxic sugar, where a class is created to wrap the lambda, and the variables that are closed over are passed into the new class. The way it is passed in still depends on the same rules. HOWEVER its not always apparent what is being closed over, and quick often its `this` that gets closed over. This is to reduce the number of new classes being created.

Comment: I dont' fully understand your example. Are there references? Thank you. Btw, I added some few code lines, some starting from a little bit farther back but I'd like to clarify in my head what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the main question to be:

> "Is [a] variable copied when passed as a parameter?"

If the variable in question is of value type, then yes, unless you specifically use the "byref" construct (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx)).

If the variable in question is of reference type, then no, the reference is copied, not the referenced object itself. It makes no difference whether or not the object is immutable.

So in general, like in C#, you won't duplicate instances simply by passing them as arguments. (The function receiving the argument could of course manually duplicate its argument, say, by invoking a copy constructor.)

Comment: I was wondering how to get the memory addr of a value type. Tried the `&` operator above but no success. Many thanks