# Error FS0001, this function was expected to have type byref<int>

Tags: f#

I have a made a simple function that wraps common F# functions of signature `'a -> 'b -> 'c option` to more "C# compliant" function as : `'a -> b -> byref<'c> -> bool`. But somehow when I try to wrap such a method in a class I am getting error FS0001 and I can't locate the error.

Code below

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

// Given a function, f: 'a -> 'b -> 'c option returns
// A new function g: 'a -> 'b -> byref<'c> -> bool
let wrapOptionF f a b (g:byref<'c>) =
    match f a b with
    | Some v ->
        do g <- v
        true
    | None -> 
        false

let tryDivide (a:int) (b:int) =
    match Math.DivRem(a,b) with
    | v, 0 -> Some v
    | _ -> None

type TryDivideWrapper() =
    static member TryDivide(a, b, [<Out>]cRef:byref<int>) : bool =
        let f = wrapOptionF tryDivide a b
        f cRef
```

The offending line is `f cRef`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028580/742594) contains a more in-depth explanation, but in short you can replace your final type definition with the following:

```
type TryDivideWrapper() =
    static member TryDivide(a, b, [<Out>]cRef:byref<int>) : bool =
        wrapOptionF tryDivide a b &cRef
```

The reason for this is that your `wrapOptionF` takes a `byref` parameter. However, `byref<int>` isn't really a type like `int` or `int ref` - it's just an indication to the compiler that your parameter should be passed by reference (like `out` in C#). Once inside your function, however, what you have is a regular `int`.

---

Edit: Note that Intellisense will show `cRef` as having type `byRef<int>`. However, if you bind another variable to `cRef`, you'll see that the type you get is a regular `int`. You can put this line inside `TryDivide` and then hover your mouse over `a` to see it:

```
let a = cRef
```

---

Using the `&` operator tells the compiler that you're passing `cRef` into `f` by reference - which is exactly what `f` needs - making the type system happy. I've tested this using a C# project, and `TryDivideWrapper.TryDivide(a, b, out c)` works as expected. Add in @MarkSeemann's `tryDivide` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive You've triggered a monster in me  http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.ie/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand the reason, but this seems to work:

```
type TryDivideWrapper() =
    static member TryDivide(a, b, [<Out>]cRef:byref<int>) : bool =
        wrapOptionF tryDivide a b &cRef
```

---

BTW, the OP `tryDivide` implementation throws an exception on `tryDivide 1 0`. Here's an alternative implementation that works:

```
let tryDivide (a:int) (b:int) =
    if b = 0
    then None
    else Some (a / b)
```

FSI:

```
> tryDivide 1 0;;
val it : int option = None
> tryDivide 10 5;;
val it : int option = Some 2
```