# Why is passing a ref type into a F# function expecting a byref a type error?

Tags: f#

```
let a = ref 0
let f (x: byref<int>) = x

f a // type error

System.Int32.TryParse("123",a) // works
```

`f a` being a type error is puzzling to me since `a` can be passed into .NET library methods with a `byref<int>` type. Why?

Edit: I think I really explained the question poorly. The type of `System.Int32.TryParse` is `string * byref<int> -> bool` and yet it works. So why can't I pass `a` into a function of type `x:byref<int> -> int`? That is all I am asking.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028377/understanding-byref-ref-and

Comment: error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type `byref<int>` but here has type `int ref`

Comment: I understand that the compiler is converting the reference to `byref` in the call to `TryParse`. What I am wondering is why isn't it doing for functions on the F# side?

Comment: @rmunn No, I can't see this particular example being addressed in the question you linked.

Comment: It explains the difference between `ref` and `byref`, which are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `ref` is a class and `byref` is a pointer. What I am wondering is whether there is an explicit reason why the implicit conversion during method calls is not being done on the F# side. Maybe instead of asking this here on SO, I should open an issue on the F# Github repo and ask there?

Comment: The reason why this thing bothers me is because I am working on a language that compiles to F# and it makes the semantics of references wonky to have special cases like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is described in section 8.13.7 of the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf).  The ability to use a `ref` when a `byref` is expected is enabled by a "type-directed conversion", but these are applied only on member invocations, not on regular function applications.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I am seeing wrong with that code is the Type Annotation is incorrect, try `:int ref` instead of `byref<int>`

Full code:

```
let a = ref 0
let f (x: int ref) = x

f a // type error

System.Int32.TryParse("123",a) // works
```

Edit:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question. So this one is a bit vague on F#'s part, I do think F# needs to improve it's error messages a bit. What is happening is since C# did not originally have tuples, they needed out parameters in order to return multiple values. So when you see a signature like `byref<int>`, that is .NET's way of telling you that is the signature of an out parameter, out parameters are for C# only. More reading [here](https://luketopia.net/2014/02/05/fsharp-and-output-parameters/).