# byref return in F# 4.5

Tags: f#, byref, return-by-reference

I am trying to add a F#-style interface to a type, that has a byref return method.
Here's the code:

```
type IPool<'P, 'T when 'T: struct> =
  abstract member GetReference: ITypedPointer<'P, 'T> -> byref<'T>

let Ref<'TPool, 'P, 'T when 'TPool :> IPool<'P, 'T>> (pool: 'TPool) pointer =
  pool.GetReference pointer
```

Now to my surprise, a similar thing worked fine until I introduced `IPool` interface. Before that Ref itself contained an implementation like `&pool.data.[idx]`, and worked fine.

I tried installing nightly build of F# Tools, cause latest release does not officially support byref returns, and PR to introduce them was recently completed: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/4888

However, I still get `error FS3209: The address of the variable 'copyOfStruct' cannot be used at this point. A method or function may not return the address of this local value.` in Visual Studio. Type `outref<T>` still does not seem to be available either. Am I missing something?

I also tried to drop the `pointer` parameter, and just return `pool.GetReference` to only get a different error message.

Addition: the ultimate goal is to be able to do

```
let aref = Ref pool ptr
let bref = Ref pool ptr
aref <- 42
assert(aref = bref)
```

e.g. give caller a direct reference to an internal memory, usually backed by an array, similar to `Span<T>`. I am making this for performance reasons, so it is not OK to allocate on every call to Ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, reducing generalization helped to get rid of the error:

```
let Ref<'P, 'T when 'T: struct> (pool: IPool<'P, 'T>) pointer = pool.GetReference pointer
```

Solution provided by

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5366#issuecomment-407521220

Though it does not explain why the original code does not compile.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's standard practice to return a `byref` type.  This type is really meant for method parameters, mostly for C# interop with `out` or `ref` parameters.  Take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028377/understanding-byref-ref-and) for a good explanation.

What you can do is change the method on your interface to take a tuple of `ITypedPointer<'P,'T>` and `byref<'T>` (usage of `byref` is not allowed with curried parameters) and return `unit` instead.  Then you can call `GetReference` like any standard .NET method with an `out` parameter in C#.  That would look something like this:

```
type ITypedPointer<'P, 'T> = interface end

type IPool<'P, 'T when 'T: struct> =
  abstract member GetReference: ITypedPointer<'P, 'T> * byref<'T> -> unit

let Ref<'TPool, 'P, 'T when 'TPool :> IPool<'P, 'T>> (pool: 'TPool) pointer =
  let mutable value = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
  pool.GetReference(pointer, &value)
  value
```

Comment: The whole idea is to return byref so that method user can do stuff like: `let x = Ref pool ptr; x <- 10`

Comment: You can actually find example at the very bottom of this file: https://github.com/lostmsu/ShortPointers/blob/5c700ee4bf7c79722c6448f9436b5ba4027c44ea/src/StructPool.fs

Comment: If you just want to mutate it from another location, why not use a standard F# `ref` Reference Cell?

Comment: Because I need the client to be able to get a reference to an array element. `let x = [| 1 |]; let r1 = ref x.[0]; let r2 = ref x.[0]; r1 := 2; !r2` will yield `1`. If I use `&x.[0]` instead, it will be `2`